"Save as" command button microsoft word
I am trying to create a job write up form and would like to add a button on it that would automatically save the open document into a specific folder on the desktop so the original would be a template. and i would also like to have it take the content of 2 cells in the first table of the document as the name of the file. Is this possible? it sounds like a lot of work for the desired application but it would make it work well for what i need to use it for
any help would be massively appreciated
thank you, this is what i have so far but i am getting an error with permissions on the active document.saveas2 line
it says "run-time error 5487:
word cannot complete the save due to a file permission error.(c:\users\techtool\desktop...\test.docm)
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String

path = "C:\Users\TECHTOOL\Desktop\Ongoing\"
filename1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:=path & filename1 & ".docm", 
FileFormat:=wdFormatFlatXMLMacroEnabled
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub


Always helps to show code you already tried, even if it didn't work the way you want.

(1) Unless you are making cumulative changes to a document, this should be a template, with a new document created from the template. (2) The saving and name could be in an AutoNew macro in the template. (3) You may want to use a QAT icon for your macro rather than a button in the document. These can be saved as part of a template or document. (4) Your question may be closed if you don't include some code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Welcome Josh! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

Josh,
This string is wrong:
filename1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text

It gets all the symbols from cell (row: 1, column: 2), including the symbol of table cell and the paraghraph mark (press ctrl + shift + 8 to display non-printing characters).
Try using debug.print to see the value your code generates (don't forget to open Immediate Window by pressing Ctrl + G - the value will appear there):
debug.print filename1 

Something like this works perfectly (it's not the best solutuion though as it will work only if there's just one row of text in a cell and there're no additional end paraghraph symbols etc.):
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim path As String
    Dim filename1 As String
    
    path = "C:\Users\TECHTOOL\Desktop\Ongoing\"
    'removing the last two symbols in filename1 
    filename1 = Mid(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text, 1, Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text) - 2)
    
    Debug.Print Len(filename1) 'to see the length of filename1 
    Debug.Print filename1 'to see what symbols filename1 contains
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 path & filename1 & ".docm"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub

I'd recommend placing content controls in the first table (each cell) and locking the section with that table (so that users can input text only in content controls) or locking content controls (so that they can't be deleted). Content controls should not allow end of paragraph marks. Then you can access content controls text:
filename1 = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("name_of_CC").Item(1).Range.Text

The alternative is getting text of the cells and filtering out all table cell symbols and paragraph marks.
In case you need to clear the table in your "template" when it is opened (put it in ThisDocument in MS Word objects):
Private Sub Document_open()
    Dim aDoc As Document
    Set aDoc = ActiveDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long 'row number
    Dim j As Long 'column number
    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = aDoc.Tables(1) 'number of your table that must be cleared

    j = 1 'start form column 1

delete_cell_text:
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count 'perform for each row in column j
        tbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = ""
    Next i
   
    j = j + 1 'number of the next column

    If j <= tbl.Columns.Count Then 'stop when j is bigger than the number of columns in table 1
        GoTo delete_cell_text 'return back to deleting text in each cell of the next column
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


would there be a way for it to use 2 cells in the first table for title? Its is currently using one of them which is brilliant but id like it to use another as well if possible, i also want it to use the value in the first row of the 6th column (both values in the title)

Just add one more string value to your file name every time you need to adjust the way it is generated (add text from a new cell).
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 path & filename1 & filename2 & ".docm", wdFormatFlatXMLMacroEnabled

Are you making a template? Or a document that will be accumulating changes made by diffrenet users (or the same user on diffrenet occasions)?
If user chooses to save changes before pressing your command button all the changes will be both in the template and in the new document.

It's a template for a job write up, I want it to save with both the customer name and job number using the button, sounds like an overly complicated way to save a document but for the application and the people that will be the using it, it really is the easiest way round things. If the changes are saved to both the template and the new document by mistake it isnt the end of the world, just means the user will have to edit the template before they use it again

Sorry, forgot to delete wdFormatFlatXMLMacroEnabled  from SaveAs line.
Do it or saved files won't open.

You can automatically clear your "template" when it's opened. I added a sub to my answer. Modify it if necessary and put it in ThisDocument in MS Word objects.
